# jQuery ignore enter key until min length in textarea, then bind to submit

Tags: jquery, html, submit

I'm looking to mimic the behavior of the Facebook comment box, using jQuery, where the field submits upon enter - but not until a minimum number of characters have been entered.

I have this version here:

```
    $(function() {
        $("textarea.commentfield").keypress(function (e) {

            // fire on enter key
            if ( (e.which == 13) && (this.value.length >= 3) ) {
```

This submits when 3 or more characters in the Textarea - however if the user hits enter before the minimum characters, it inserts a line return.

How can I prevent this behavior - essentially ignore the enter key until the minimum length is reached?

Comment: Is there a separate `.submit` event?

Comment: no, this is a textarea without a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) will keep the key pressed from being displayed

```js
$(function() {
  $("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      if (this.value.length >= 3) {
        console.log('submitting');
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Juan's answer, you can `return false` from an event handler to prevent its default behavior.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("textarea.commentfield").keypress(function(e) {
    // fire on enter key
    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
      if (this.value.length >= 3) {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" class="commentfield"></textarea>
```

Note that `return false` only works in jQuery handlers, not in handlers using `addEventListener`. See http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Given overall solution , might be useful

Comment: How to separate js code and html with fiddle. any help links? I mean run code snippet option

Comment: Press `ctrl+m`, the inline code snippet will show with CSS/HTML/JS and output panes

Comment: Given the textarea is submitted via AJAX and is not an element of a form (note my comment in question) would this actually submit?